# Downcasting Guava map classes

Tags: java, guava

I have about a month of work into a system that is using a guava datatype of

```
ImmutableMap<String, Object>
```

Things work great, even my developers love it.  Its awesome.  Until yesterday.  We have a recordset that we have to bring in as an ImmutableListMultimap and we have to cast it to our ImmutableMap type.

here is our compile error

```
ImmutableListMultimap<String, Object> tst = new bla bla bla;
        ImmutableMap<String, Object> tst2 = (ImmutableMap<String, Object>) tst.asMap();
```

The error itself is

```
Cannot cast from ImmutableMap<String,Collection<Object>> to ImmutableMap<String,Object>
```

Now doing this cast isn't an option.  It must be done or we have to go back and reengineer a month of work.  Not going to happen.  The only option I have right now to solve this is to build a factory class that iterates the `tst` variable, recasting the values to basic objects and dumping that into `tst2`.  But, this tst var could contain thousands of entries which makes that solution unwise.

Another option is Apache Collections Transforms, but since those are just iterators as well, I don't gain much.

Is there anything more elegant that I can do to downcast a generic or has Sun's brilliant concept of generics type erasure just doomed me.

Comment: What about `ImmutableMap<String, ?> tst2 = ...` ? After all, `ImmutableMap<K, Object>` and `ImmutableMap<K, Collection<Object>>` are not related types.

Comment: How is doing this with a cast the crucial outcome of a month of work?

Comment: This is a good idea, im going to give it a shot and see if i have any side effects.  Not sure if it will break anything we already have

Comment: because thats a lot of code to redo, rethink, retest, update unit tests to account for multiple types, etc.  we can't afford a change like that right now, no time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be cast for a good reason, but there's simple workaround:

```
ImmutableMap<String, Object> tst2 =
    (ImmutableMap<String, Object>) (Object) tst.asMap();
```

---

This looks possibly a bit saner:

```
    ImmutableListMultimap<String, Object> tst = ...
    ImmutableMap<String, ? extends Collection<Object>> asMap = tst.asMap();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ImmutableMap<String, Object> tst2 = (ImmutableMap<String, Object>) asMap;
```

The generic system is not perfect (if it was, it'd even more complicated) and sometimes it's hard to understand. The unchecked cast above is safe because of the immutability: There's no way to put in an `Object` (this would go against the `Map<String, Collection<Object>>` signature).

Comment: HA!!  Awesome.  Didn't realize you could chain casts like that.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is this really simpler than just using a wildcard? Once you've suppressed the warnings etc, you've got a more verbose solution.

Comment: @AndyTurner The OP explicitly wrote "Now doing this cast isn't an option.", so I'm assuming they want `Object` and not a `?`. Otherwise they could stick with `Collection<Object>` and have no problem at all.

Comment: @maaartinus You don't need to cast anyway to use the values as instances of `Object`. See code below.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ImmutableMap.copyOf` method, with explicit constraints:

```
ImmutableMap<String, Object> tst2 = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>copyOf(tst.asMap());
```

Note that this [doesn't necessarily copy the map](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.java?r=c29d8ae455fac7d3a416e92cd60be2d1f33d11f6#252) - under some (many) circumstances, `tst == tst2` (they are identical references).

If you absolutely must avoid making a copy of the map, you would need to use a wildcard type, since `ImmutableMap<K, Object>` and `ImmutableMap<K, Collection<Object>>` are not related types:

```
ImmutableMap<String, ?> tst2 = tst.asMap();
```

The fact that the value is a wildcard type shouldn't affect your ability to do anything with the map values as `Object`s:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : tst2.entrySet()) {
  Object value = entry.getValue();
  //...
}
```

Comment: upvote because no type safety warning and as it is Immutable no need to put which is not allowed on wildcard.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. If they could use `ImmutableMap<String, ?>`, then why not to use `ImmutableMap<String, Collection<Object>>` directly and save any casting?

Comment: I have no idea why they want to do it, but subverting the type system by casting to a completely general type and then back to a specific feels unnecessary, vaguely dangerous and verbose.

Comment: the reason is we are serializing these objects to a cache.  we built into it one type to be saved that we can use for anything.  <string, object>.  to change it now with 6 devs going balls out writing code on top of this is huge, especially under the time constraints we currently have.  I do want to try the wildcard idea, but i just simply don't have the time to risk screwing it up at the moment.  once i get this release out next week, i will have a little time to see if i can refine it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

So, one approach that will not generate any compile warnings would be, instead of a cast, to use `ImmutableMap.copyOf`.  This will not actually perform a copy, as it can detect that would be redundant, but it will take an `ImmutableMap<? extends K, ? extends V>` and return an `ImmutableMap<K, V>`.

It will still be a constant time operation, and a cast under the surface, but it will not generate warnings.